# .NET Bundler - How to include files with multiple '.' in their filename?

Tags: javascript, .net, bundle

I'm creating a bundle using the following code.

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/WidgetsBundle").IncludeDirectory(
              "~/Content/widgets/", "j*", false));
    }
}
```

I'd like every file beginning with '`j`' in the directory to be included.

This works for files with names like '`javascript.js`'.

The problem is that files with names like '`javascript.hello.js`' do **not** get included.

**How can I adjust my search pattern to include these files?**

Comment: I'm working on VB but what happen to you is not happening to me after I tried both: `bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Jbundle").Include("~/Scripts/test/j*"))` and `bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Jbundle").IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/test/", "j*", False))` working for me.. It not only bringing `javascript.hello.js` file but also `ja.va.sc.ri.pt.hel.lo.js` along with `javascript.js` So there must be something else that is wrong with the code..

Comment: How do you know that it is not included? For example in an easy way I set `javascript.js` file's content to: `var j1 = 1;` and likewise `javascript.hello.js` content to: `var j2 = 2;` and in firebug I can see that `Jbundle`'s content being: `var j2=2,j1=1`